# trigger lambda cloudwatch vs api gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to trigger a lambda function periodically, let's say, every one minutes, should I trigger it cloudfront or api gateway? what are the pros and cons between these two method?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to trigger a AWS Lambda function periodically is to use a [CloudWatch Events scheduled expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html):

> You can create rules that self-trigger on an automated schedule in
>   CloudWatch Events using cron or rate expressions. All scheduled events
>   use UTC time zone and the minimum precision for schedules is 1 minute.
>
> CloudWatch Events supports cron expressions and rate expressions. Rate
>   expressions are simpler to define but don't offer the fine-grained
>   schedule control that cron expressions support. For example, with a
>   cron expression, you can define a rule that triggers at a specified
>   time on a certain day of each week or month. In contrast, rate
>   expressions trigger a rule at a regular rate, such as once every hour
>   or once every day.

Example from the AWS CLI:

```
aws events put-rule --region us-east-1 --name "MinuteLambdaFunction" --schedule-expression "cron(0/1 * * * ? *)"
aws events put-targets --region us-east-1 --rule MinuteLambdaFunction --targets "Id"="1","Arn"="arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:MyFunctionName"
```